# How to open and read a file

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, fortran95

I have this Fortran code that reads two columns of data from an external file:

```
  PRINT*, ' Q1                Q2  '
  DO 2 J = 1, NPTS
  READ(20,*) Q1(J),Q2(J)

  WRITE(*,98) Q1(J),Q2(J)
```

So the file 20 is used, but it doesn't seem to like any names I use in the file, so the question is, what should I name the file as? It's a `.txt` by the way.

Comment: open(unit=20,file="what you want") (to put before the loop 2)

Comment: How are you opening unit 20?  It does not matter what you call the file as long as you open it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not `read` from files, but from `units`. So if you want to read from unit `20` as in your example, you need open a file using that unit first. This is typically done with an `open` statement, as suggested in the comments. For a file called `yourfile.txt`, your program would then read

```
  OPEN( unit=20, file='yourfile.txt',  status='old', &
        action='read', iostat=stat )
  if(stat /= 0) stop 'Could not open file'

  PRINT*, ' Q1                Q2  '

  DO 2 J = 1, NPTS
    READ(20,*) Q1(J),Q2(J)

    WRITE(*,98) Q1(J),Q2(J)
    ! ...
```

If you don't open a file first, at least `gfortran` and `ifort` try to read from a file named `fort.<unit>`, in your case `fort.20`. I couldn't find a reference in the Standard for that behavior, though.

Don't forget to close the file after reading, and try to avoid fixed unit numbers. If your compiler supports it, use the `newunit=` specifier when opening files.